# How to Sample Smooth Random Walks of Instantaneous Frequency

Tags: discrete-signals, noise, aliasing

I want to generate a random sequence for instantaneous frequency with as little aliasing as possible (i.e I expect to see as close to constant amplitude as possible, with only the frequency varying). What I have so far seems close, but in some cases results in a few frequencies with less-than-expected amplitudes:

```
def ms(x):
    return (np.abs(x)**2.0).mean()

def normalize(y, x=None):
    if x is not None:
        x = ms(x)
    else:
        x = 1.0
    return y * np.sqrt( x / ms(y) )

def brown(N, state=None):
    state = np.random.RandomState() if state is None else state
    uneven = N%2
    X = state.randn(N//2+1+uneven) + 1j * state.randn(N//2+1+uneven)
    S = (np.arange(len(X))+1)# Filter
    y = (np.fft.irfft(X/S)).real
    if uneven:
        y = y[:-1]
    return normalize(y)

inst_freq = np.cumsum(brown(100))
inst_freq -= inst_freq.min() - 1
inst_freq /= inst_freq.max()
rectified_inst_freq = 1.0 / (np.floor(1.0 / inst_freq))

plt.plot(inst_freq)
plt.plot(rectified_inst_freq, 'r')
plt.show()
plt.plot(np.cos(np.cumsum(np.pi * inst_freq)))
plt.show()
plt.plot(np.cos(np.cumsum(np.pi * rectified_inst_freq)))
plt.show()
```

The `rectified_inst_freq` variable is attempting to round the instantaneous frequencies to the a frequency with an integer period, this helps a lot with the aliasing, but not entirely. Results that show the strange high-frequency amplitude problem (the middle graph before rectification, and the bottom graph after):

[image]

The high frequency portion at the end of the rectified signal should have amplitude 1, but it is stuck at .75. I think this has to do with aliasing, but I am not sure how to fix it. In some scenarios (particularly ones that start at a high frequency) the amplitude is correct (see below)

[image]

Comment: okay, lemme get this straight... you're first creating a curve (from brownian random process) that is your instantaneous frequency.  from that you are generating a sinusoid that has phase which is the integral (or cumulative sum) of the instantaneous frequency.  then you *"rectify"* that instantaneous frequency but rounding to the nearest value that has a period that is an integer number of samples.  and you plot both results.  $$ $$ so what, exactly, is your question or problem?

Comment: the amplitude difference is a result of a low sample rate and a plotting function that only draws piecewise linear plots.  either increase the sample rate or limit the instantaneous frequencies to much lower than 1/2 the sample rate.  or get a better plotting function that does better than linear interpolation.

Comment: Re: rectification.. This was my attempt at fixing the aliasing.. it's not a critical part of what I am doing.

Comment: well, if the frequencies are less than Nyquist, that is 1/2 of the sample rate, there isn't really **aliasing** issues going on, but there **may** be **imaging** or **reconstruction** issues.  if you had decent sinc() based reconstruction and more points to draw the plots, your amplitude would look better.

Comment: Re: limiting the frequencies... I thought I was doing that by limiting the highest frequency to pi - should it be pi/2 instead?

Comment: I don't think it's an imaging issue -- the actual signal itself is evaluated to .5 on those points np.cos(np.cumsum(np.pi * rectified_inst_freq)) = 
array([ 0.99896106,  0.99021568,  0.95777268,  0.88265998,  0.74608855,
        0.53878456,  0.27892597, -0.01312373, [...], -0.62780547, 0.62780547,
       -0.62780547,  0.62780547, -0.62780547,  0.62780547, -0.62780547,
        0.62780547, -0.62780547,  0.62780547, -0.62780547,  0.62780547,
       -0.62780547,  0.62780547, -0.62780547,  0.62780547, -0.62780547])

Comment: Robert, it **is** an imaging issue.  sometimes people (even books or DSP articles) are imprecise with semantics and call the images "aliases" in the frequency domain.  when you sample, the original signal (both positive and negative frequencies) is translated by integer multiples of the sampling frequency and overlapped and added.  a true sinc() brickwall filter will kill those images, but linear interpolation will not kill them.  so you actually have a constant amplitude cosine waveform with those samples but it **looks** like you don't.

Comment: try restricting your instantaneous frequency to less than 1/10 the sample rate and see how bad it looks with linear interpolation.

Comment: I am not quite understanding what you mean about the imaging issue (are you talking about the actual rendering of the graph?), but you are correct - restricting my instantaneous frequency does fix the problem!

Comment: do you know the difference between an **"image"** and an **"alias"**?  properly or adequately sampled continuous-time signals have *images*, but if they are sampled adequately, they don't have *aliases*.  properly reconstructed discrete-time signals (that requires a sinc() function) will kill the images.  linear interpolation does not totally kill the images.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52226/discussion-between-robert-and-robert-bristow-johnson).

Comment: i'm too lazy for that.

Comment: I always find chat to be the least useful thing – it really takes away a lot of time from those who might be able to answer, without leaving a trace that can help future readers. So, whilst I think it's often OK to push "idle" discussions from comments into chat,I'd say it's almost never a good choice for discussions relevant to the topic.Robert,if you haven't,please read up on how images in the signal interpolation sense happen.You might also want to add the observation you gained by trying with the reduced signal frequency-to-sample-rate ration to your question,so that it's easier to answer!

Comment: I completely understand about the chat thing, I will try and distill what @robertbristow-johnson taught me in chat and post it as a comment (most of which, as you are pointing out, are what images are in a signal processing sense)

as for the "reduced signal frequency-to-sample-rate ration", what do you mean?

Comment: Chat: There is a difference between an "image" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem#/media/File:ReconstructFilter.png) and an "alias" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem#/media/File:AliasedSpectrum.png) in DSP, and in this particular example, my issue was with imaging. The practical intuition is that my signal does have constant amplitude, but the "peaks" are happening between integer values (my sampling rate). Because we are linearly interpolating signal values, it can look like the peaks are smaller than they really are.